# How to store dynamic value and reuse in Webdriver Ruby test

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I'm writing a ruby webdriver test that needs to store a dynamic value such as an order ID to use later on in the text. I think I need to extract the value from the string and then store it as a variable to call for future use.

The string looks like this and I just need to extract/store the numeric value.

```
<span class="receiptNum hidden-xs">Receipt #: 12303430</span>
```

Any tips or examples on how to extract that value and create a variable for future use would be great!

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to Selenium and Ruby/Rspec so I have been researching how to approach this scenario. I've researched this site and others and have seen some similar questions for other programming languages but not Ruby/Rspec specific which is why I submitted my question here. From what I've seen, maybe a regex to pull the numeric value from the span tag would work best? but then I would need to store this value as a variable to pass in the future to test a order lookup feature.

Comment: I added some code to test that the element is displayed on the page following a successful order.  expect(@driver.find_element(:class, "receiptNum hidden-xs").displayed?).to be_truthy

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings.  As it shows under the API Example section, you can call `element.text` to extract the text after locating the specified element (which could then be assigned for a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the text (only numbers) out of the this element, try using the following code:

```
@numbers = @driver.find_element(:css=>'receiptNum').text.scan(\d+)
```

Currently I am saving this number in an instance variable which can be used again in the same test as it will flow around with the test object till the test finishes.

Other option include saving it in a temp txt file and reading from it when required.

Note: Fetching data now and using it later is not a good practice, try not to use this very frequently.

Hope it helps!!!