# Save text and output on textbox (Ruby Selenium/Webdriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to get a text from an element and then I want to write that text into another element which is available in another window when window switch.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path="C:/chromedriver.exe"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.get 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJMqNGK1e2j4VjS8K2kS5wloKpEaHu_GTxMl2KueUCM/edit?usp=sharing'
sleep 8 
browser.action.send_keys(:arrow_down).perform
browser.action.send_keys(:left_control, 'c').perform
sleep 1 
browser.execute_script("window.open('http://10.19.252.220:25780/PortalCDT/')")
browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
    browser.switch_to.window handle
  end
sleep 5
    browser.find_element(:id, "IdClient").click
    browser.find_element(:id, "IdClient").send_keys(:left_control, 'v')
    browser.find_element(:id, "ConfirmButton").click
    puts "Disp. Cash: " + browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucInfoCliente_lblDispCash").text
    column4 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucInfoCliente_lblDispCash").text
    puts "-------------------------------------"
    sleep 1
     browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
        browser.switch_to.window handle
        sleep 1
        browser.action.send_keys(:arrow_right).perform
        browser.action.send_keys("Id Here").perform
        browser.action.send_keys(:arrow_right).perform
        browser.action.send_keys(:colunmn4).text
    browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
        browser.switch_to.window handle
        sleep 1
        browser.action.send_keys(:arrow_down).perform
        browser.action.send_keys(:left_control, 'c').perform
    end
    browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
        browser.switch_to.window handle
    end
```

tried to save the text into column4 variable and then I want to write it into a text field which is another window.

Html code to copy text

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucInfoCliente_lblDispRotativo">2870,14</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Reframe your question, it's not understandable. You want to get a text from a particular element and then you click some button which will open a new window where you would be finding a text_field?

Comment: Almost that. I want to get a text from a element, copy him and type this element.

When the code do "browser.window_handles.each do |handle|", he will switch to a Google Driver spreadsheet and ready to type.

Comment: so clicking a button opens the spreadsheet for you in which you want to type the content which you copied first?

Comment: I just edit the question with it (sorry for the delay). When the codes do "browser.window_handles.each do |handle| browser.switch_to.window handle", he will ctrl+tab to spreadsheet already opened.

After window switch, he will paste the content.

Comment: I think this is quite similar for what I trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457167/how-to-store-dynamic-value-and-reuse-in-webdriver-ruby-test but can't reproduce in my test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer:

```
value = browser.find_element('span#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucInfoClient_lblDispCash')
value_text = value.text
text_area = browser.find_element('textbox#whatver_id')
text_area.send_keys(value_text, :enter).perform
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, why are you accepting my answer? Accept your answer.

Comment: Ty hahahhaha, I tried to click on both because ur answer still useful too but the system dnt allow that hahahaha

Comment: All right! Other user will look into the accepted answer for their reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of mistake in your program.

1)To pass,control+c, you should pass`[:control,"c"]`, not like `(:control, 'c')`, The difference here is, your code would pass control and c sequentially but code `[:control,'c']` would hold the control key while it presses c. Do you see the difference?

2)Why are you opening a new tab while you intend to open another url? Open another Browser, that would not need your shift in Window.

Since I can't open your second URL, I copy your intended cell from spreadsheet and paste it in Google search textfield.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'    
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome    
driver.navigate.to 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMOaVoDF3PsXCgqiEQgYWe8CCO7PcDwsqHpEGT2no3I/edit?usp=sharing'    
driver.action.send_keys(:arrow_down).perform    
driver.action.send_keys([:control, 'c']).perform    
driver1=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome    
driver1.navigate.to("https://www.google.com/")    
driver1.action.send_keys([:control, 'v']).perform
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I needed to clean the house with my wife this weekend. Ty for claryfing me that Rajagopalan! I'll never see that by myself hahahah.
It's possible to ctrl+c a text object too to paste in the spreadsheet? I'm trying to put him in cache here:  column4 = browser.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucInfoCliente_lblDispCash").text
 and tried to paste him here: browser.action.send_keys(:colunmn4).text . I just put the object's html code in question.

Comment: @holyonline okay.